# Verb for putting a stick through a hole

Tags: word-request, verbs

Imagine a doughnut. Imagine a stick. Imagine using the stick to lift it by [pushing/putting] the stick through the hole in that doughnut. What is the correct verb for the act of putting the stick through? I want a verb to describe the activity of the stick going through.

> I [___-ed] the stick through the donut's hole.

Comment: There are various possibilities, with various degrees of sexual suggestiveness.

Comment: Does "stuck" work?

Comment: (Or just "put"?)

Comment: *Some* doughnuts have a hole in the middle, so in a context such as [She **skewered** a donut hole on the nail of her index finger](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22skewered+a+donut%22) the intended sense is that she put her finger through the hole, so she could hold the doughnut out (we also use [***spear** a donut*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22speared+a+donut%22) in such contexts). But peas don't have holes, and just look how often *She* *[**speared** a pea](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22speared+a+pea%22)* *[on a dining plate, using a fork]* occurs.

Comment: Personally, I'd be fine with ***threading*** doughnuts (the kind with holes) on a stick, but I'm not gonna bother searching Google Books for examples.

Comment: To me, "threading" implies more than one donut, by analogy with beads. But skewer or spear are good in the singular case.

Comment: 'Poked' might not get you arrested ;)

Comment: @FumbleFingers, the expression "donut hole" in the linked source clearly refers not to the central hole in a torus-shaped confection but rather to a small ball of fried dough, supposedly made from the dough punched out to *make* that hole.

Comment: @BrianDonovan: If that's what you think, I'm not gonna argue with you. But I will just say that was my *first* thought, which I discarded after a quick look at the relevant book page. They did once used to (facetiously) sell the "punched-out holes" from Polo mints in the UK, but are you seriously suggesting that "the pink donut box" in that story contains "holes", rather than / as well as "donuts with holes"?

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Yes I am seriously suggesting that, the "as well as" version. "Kobra skewered a donut hole on the nail of her index finger and fed it to Cher." The antecedent of "it" is "donut hole." Neither a vacuity nor one's own index finger or nail can well be *fed* to one's neighbor. Also, the verb "skewered" would seem to suggest that the fingernail was piercing something, not just passing through a pre-existing orifice.

Comment: @BrianDonovan: I said I didn't want to get bogged down in such a pointless difference of opinion, but you're goading me. I remember 60 years ago that my mother (facetiously) fried us the holes instead of kneading them back into more "complete" doughnuts, but I don't recall hearing of the facetious sale of such holes as a commercial "USP". Bear in mind it's her ***index*** finger she's using to secure the item, which she then needs to proffer to another person to nibble. That bit of cooked "hole" dough wouldn't be much fatter than her finger, so I'm afraid I just can't visualize it your way! :)

Comment: Donut holes as a commercial USP - google Timbits. Famously "donut holes", in exactly that facetious way, the [fictitious] bits from the middle of donuts.

Comment: Kobra's pronoun (OK, possessive determiner) appears to be "her"; be she woman or be she drag queen, I have no trouble visualizing a nail well capable of impaling a Timbit without involving the attached finger.

Comment: Why do people write 'donut' when discussing doughnuts?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: I doubt we can attribute this *particular* "modernized spelling" to Webster, but you never know. Interestingly, I see the full OED's earliest citation is **1782** - ***Fried Donotes.*** Pick the bones out of *that!*

Answer (score 4):

**Insert** the stick through the doughnut/donut's hole

**Slip** the stick into …

From [Oxford Languages](https://www.google.com/search?q=insert%20definition&oq=insert%20def&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0i512l9.6394j1j15&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) via Google

> ### insert
>
> *verb*
> /ɪnˈsəːt/
> place, fit, or push (something) into something else.
> "Claudia inserted her key in the lock"

Answer (score 0):

'...stick...', '...poke...', '...shove...', 'kkinsert...'.....